# How to delete all rows in a group except the newest one?

Tags: mysql, sql-delete, delete-row, unique-constraint

Say, I have a table similar to this:

```
CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `application_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `company_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

I want to make `application_id` unique, but there're some duplicates in the table already. How can I group by `application_id` and remove all records per group, leaving just the one with the highest `id`?

Comment: It can be quicker to create a new table, retaining just the rows you want to keep, and then replacing the old table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
delete from mytable
where id not in 
(
  select max(id)
  from mytable
  group by application_id
)
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems that I can also use [`DELETE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/delete.html) with `JOIN`: `DELETE t1 FROM mytable t1 JOIN mytable t2 ON t1.application_id = t2.application_id WHERE t1.id < t2.id`. Which approach is better?

Comment: There is no "better". Just use one of them.

Comment: Ok, are they at least equivalent? :)

Comment: Maybe one of them performs better depending on indexes and table size. Besides that it does not matter.

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.